# ERROR:Error [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно (при попытке установить библиотеки Python)

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-8

Возникает ошибка WinError 87 параметр задан неверно, при попытке загрузить kivy через командную строку, или при попытке подключить библиотеку sympy в Pycharm(Параметр задан неверно while executing command python setup.py egg_info), тоже самое показывать когда я пытаюсь загрузить что то в VS. Везде выдает одну и ту же ошибку.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить. Заранее предупреждаю, перезагрузка всего вышеперечисленного не помогла

Comment: Какая версия python и pip? Может быть надо обновить pip. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Версия python 3.8.2. Не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отключить антивирус. Мне помогло